# How to allow characters and whitespaces in an exception in regex?

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Given the input:

> 1993年8月にデビュー。。。同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、10連続連対を達成し、1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、安楽死の措置がとられた。

Desired output is:

```
["1993年8月にデビュー。"
 "同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、", "10連続連対を達成し、",
 "1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、", "1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。",
 "1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、", "6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった",
 "（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、", "第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。",
 "第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。",
 "競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、", "1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、", "安楽死の措置がとられた。"]
```

I've tried the following regex:

```
import re

text= str("1993年8月にデビュー。"
          "同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、10連続連対を達成し、"
          "1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。"
          "1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった"
          "（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。"
          "第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。"
          "競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、安楽死の措置がとられた。")

re.split(r'([^! ? 。、]*[!?。、]{1,3})', text)
```

That splits the punctuations correctly but also split on the space, outputs:

```
['',
 '1993年8月にデビュー。',
 '',
 '同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、',
 '',
 '10連続連対を達成し、',
 '1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† ',
 '3]、',
 '1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† ',
 '3]に選出された。',
 '',
 '1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、',
 '6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった（GI ',
 'は5戦して未勝利）が、',
 '',
 '第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。',
 '',
 '第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。',
 '',
 '競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、',
 '',
 '1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、',
 '',
 '安楽死の措置がとられた。',
 '']
```

These segments were broken wrongly because space wasn't included in the allowed characters of the first optional group:

```
'1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、',
'1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。',
...,
'6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、'
```

**How to allow characters and whitespaces in an exception in regex?**

Comment: Would `re.findall()` work better than split here? You could do something like `re.findall(r'[^。、]+[。、]', text)`

Comment: The in-/outputs are just examples. Is there a way to include space on top of the exclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output shows a split before a parenthesis that wasn't in your regular expression attempt.  Assuming that is an error, this works:

```
#coding:utf8
import re
text = '''1993年8月にデビュー。。。同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、10連続連対を達成し、1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、安楽死の措置がとられた。'''

desired = ["1993年8月にデビュー。",
           "同年11月から1995年3月にかけてクラシック三冠を含むGI5連勝、",
           "10連続連対を達成し、",
           "1993年JRA賞最優秀3歳牡馬[† 3]、",
           "1994年JRA賞年度代表馬および最優秀4歳牡馬[† 3]に選出された。",
           "1995年春に故障（股関節炎）を発症したあとはその後遺症から低迷し、",
           "6戦して重賞を1勝するにとどまった（GI は5戦して未勝利）が、",
           "第44回阪神大賞典におけるマヤノトップガンとのマッチレースや短距離戦である第26回高松宮杯への出走によってファンの話題を集めた。",
           "第26回高松宮杯出走後に発症した屈腱炎が原因となって1996年10月に競走馬を引退した。",
           "競走馬を引退したあとは種牡馬となったが、",
           "1998年9月に胃破裂を発症し、",
           "安楽死の措置がとられた。"]

actual = re.findall(r'([^!?。、]*[!?。、])[!?。、]*', text)
print(desired == actual)
```

Output:

```
True
```